# How to mirror (flip horizontally) and image using expression encoder and .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk, expression-encoder-4

I am building a application and it seems that image is wrongly mirrored (if I raise my left finger up, it shows my right finder is raised and vice versa).

Here is some of my code

```
 <Grid>
   <WindowsFormsHost Name="WinFormsHost" Height="960" Width="1280">
      <forms:Panel x:Name="WebcamPanel" RightToLeft="Yes" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
 </Grid>
```

and

```
_job = new LiveJob();
_deviceSrc = _job.AddDeviceSource(video, audio);
_deviceSrc.PreviewWindow = new PreviewWindow(new HandleRef(WebcamPanel, WebcamPanel.Handle));
```

How do I mirror the live stream from webcam?

Comment: Did you ever have any luck finding a solution for this?

Comment: @BradMoore expression encoder does not support it. I decided not to use expression encoder. I am now using intel realsense 3d camera which has a sdk written in c# and it supports mirroring. [This is the link to sdk](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-realsense-sdk)

Comment: Are you using this with their specific cameras or just using it as a basic way to display video streams?

Comment: I am using their specific camera, it does not work with any other camera.